# PHP - Trailing return at end of generated XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm generating some XML from a database query as follows:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
 $doc->formatOutput = true;
 $contactsElement = $doc->createElement('contacts');
 $doc->appendChild($contactsElement);

 foreach($contacts as $contact){
    $firstName = $contact->getField('first') ;
    $lastName = $contact->getField('last') ;

    $contactElement = $doc->createElement('contact');
    $firstNameElement = $doc->createElement('first_name', $firstName);
    $lastNameElement = $doc->createElement('last_name', $lastName);

    $contactElement->appendChild($firstNameElement);
    $contactElement->appendChild($lastNameElement);
    $contactsElement->appendChild($contactElement);
}

 echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This is working well but it is generating an additional line after the closing  at the end. Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <contacts>
    <contact>
        <first_name>Penny</first_name>
        <last_name>Lancaster</last_name>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <first_name>Geoff</first_name>
        <last_name>McDermott</last_name>
    </contact>
 </contacts>
 // blank line is here
```

I can't see what could be causing this or if there's a syntax change I need to make - any suggestions as to how to prevent the trailing blank line from appearing in the generated XML?

Comment: Do you have a end `?>`-tag in your file? If so, remove it

Comment: I did have a closing ?> tag - have removed that but still get the same result with the trailing blank line at the end of the XML.

Comment: Added my fix as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why there is a trailing new line, but you can solve it with this:

```
echo trim($doc->saveXML());
```